# Its is showing that cannot find symbol can any one fix it?

Tags: java, android, html, android-mediaplayer, mp3

Ive tried copying the instance of main class to sub class but it says cant find symbol
Below are the code ive tried
Here is my HTML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/shiva" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="509dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
        android:text="@string/play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bp1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="410dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
        android:text="@string/pause" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bp2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="308dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
        android:text="@string/stop" />


</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my java code

```
package com.example.rd;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button Play;
    Button Pause;
    Button Stop;

    MediaPlayer md;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Play = findViewById(R.id.bp);
        Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                md = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.rudhra);
                md.start();
            }

            MediaPlayer md;
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    Pause = findViewById(R.id.bp1);
                    Pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            md = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.rudhra);
                            md.pause();
                        }

                        MediaPlayer md;
                        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);
                                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                                Stop = findViewById(R.id.bp2);
                                Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        md = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.rudhra);
                                        md.stop();
                                    }


                                });
                            };

                        });
                    }



            });
    }
```

Here im getting 2 errors

1.cannot find symbol
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

2.cannot find symbol
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

As im beginner can any1 help me to fix it

Comment: „*…Here is my HTML CODE…*“ — I would change that to  „*XML*“. And I'm pretty sure it's called a „*manifest*“. I'm not so sure it could be called „*code*“ though.  —  „*Here im getting 2 errors*“  — Both *1* and *2* look identical. „*…can any1 help me to fix it…*“  — You might want to proofread your question content some more first.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about Activity Lifecycle first. According to it an activity has only one oncreat() method in its lifecycle. Here you seem to have added two oncreate().
Remove the second one and your code will work.